# Jquery Center Browser on Newly Displayed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, center

I am using `.show()` to show a new snippet of text in a div. This new snippet is at the bottom of the page and I want to make sure that the user's browser is centered on this new snippet.

I am concerned with it being centered vertically.

Comment: Centered vertically or both horizontally and vertically? To make it visible at the top of the viewport, you could just do `$(document).scrollTop($('div.newDiv').offset().top);`

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. You should read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know how far the text is offset from the top of the page. Then you need to subtract half the browser's viewport height.

```
var offset = $('.some-text').offset();
var vp = $(window).height();
$(window).scrollTop(offset.top - vp/2);
```

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/nNn26/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2 which probably does exactly that.